# “Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance”

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

i posted this question before and it was closed. my problem is different from the others
i got this message in one page of signin
when user entered wrong username or password in login control. this message is appeared
but if the username and password is correct. it works fine and the user can login.
my control is :

```
 <asp:Login ID="loginPane" runat="server" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="11px" LoginButtonText="Login"
                                                RememberMeSet="True" TitleText="" Width="314px" Height="201px" BackColor="gray">
                                                <TextBoxStyle BorderColor="Gray" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Tahoma"
                                                    Font-Size="11px" Width="200px" />
                                                <LabelStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                                <LoginButtonStyle BorderColor="Gray" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
                                                <LayoutTemplate>
                                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;
                                                        width: 325px; height: 217px; background-color: Gray;">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td style="width: 325px">
                                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 319px; height: 196px">
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td align="left">
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="width: 312px" align="left">
                                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" BorderColor="Gray" BorderStyle="Solid"
                                                                                BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="16px" Height="32px" Width="260px"
                                                                                ForeColor="Gray" placeholder="Username" BackColor="white"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName"
                                                                                ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="loginPane">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td align="left" style="height: 17px">
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="height: 17px; width: 312px;" align="left">
                                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" BorderColor="Gray" BorderStyle="Solid"
                                                                                TextMode="Password" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="16px" Height="32px"
                                                                                Width="260px" type='password' placeholder="Password" ForeColor="Gray"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password"
                                                                                ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="loginPane">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td colspan="2" style="height: 25px" align="left">
                                                                            <br />
                                                                            &nbsp;
                                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server" Checked="True" Text="Remember me next time."
                                                                                ForeColor="white" Font-Size="small" />
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color: red">
                                                                            <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <%-- style="opacity: 1; filter: alpha(opacity=100); -moz-opacity: 1;
                                                                            -khtml-opacity: 1;"--%>
                                                                        <td align="right" colspan="2">
                                                                            <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" BorderColor="#FFF8C6" BorderStyle="None"
                                                                                BorderWidth="1px" CommandName="Login" Height="34px" Text="Login" ValidationGroup="loginPane"
                                                                                Width="90px" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="#C11B17" Font-Bold="True" BackColor="White"
                                                                                OnClick="LoginButton_Click" />
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </LayoutTemplate>
                                            </asp:Login>
```

this message appear when i publish on my machine but when publishing on remote server i got : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections

and when run on VS it works fine and show message of login failing that i show to user

Comment: That error has nothing to do with the code posted. You have a problem with your connection string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks all,

the first error occur as i have sql express running so i have to stop it 
and the second one occur when try by login button and fail. it try to login via login control
so i have to set login authenticate to false